# Custom Error Documents Not Loading on Local Dev System

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

The .htaccess works fine on the live server but here on my development system, it does not appear to be doing so. If I purposely enter an invalid address, it just gives the basic Apache error.

It is enabled in Apache2.conf with ***AccessFileName .htaccess*** but is there anything else that needs to be enabled to make it work? At one point it was working but many system updates later, I just noticed that it is not.

```
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options -Indexes Includes +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 400 /messages/validate.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 401 /messages/validate.php?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 /messages/validate.php?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 /messages/validate.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 406 /messages/validate.php?error=406
ErrorDocument 408 /messages/validate.php?error=408
ErrorDocument 500 /messages/validate.php?error=500

<Files .htaccess,db_mysql.php,config.php,common.php>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Read about the `AllowOverride` setting in the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you but odd it was working, then suddenly wasn't! Now that it is, some errors, such as 403, do not seem to like to use a nice page to display them but fortunately they are all but non-existent on my site so it's mainly 404 that I care about.